# Can we say in this situation that $G \simeq \operatorname{im} f \oplus \ker f$?

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Somewhere I saw an assertion about a group homomorphism. $\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z$ denotes the ring of integers mod $m$. The symbol $(\mathbb Z / m \mathbb Z)^\times$ stands for the multiplicative group of all units in the ring.

The assertion:

> Let $p$ be a prime number and $n$ a positive integer. If $f:(\mathbb Z / p^n \mathbb Z)^\times \to (\mathbb Z / p \mathbb Z)^\times $ is a multiplicative group homomorphism defined by $ x+(p^n) \mapsto x + (p) $, then $(\mathbb Z / p^n \mathbb Z)^\times$ is isomorphic to the direct sum $ \operatorname {im} f \oplus \ker f. $

But I don't see why this holds. Is there any general theorem ensuring this?

Any answer would be appreciated whether it uses a theorem or not.

Comment: That's because the image $(Z/pZ)^\times$ is a direct factor of $(Z/p^nZ)^\times \cong (Z/pZ)^\times \times (Z/p^{n-1}Z)^\times$. (I would call this the direct product rather than the direct sum.) So this follows from the known structure of the group $(Z/p^nZ)^\times$.

Comment: @DerekHolt What do you mean by the known structure of $(Z/p^n Z)^\times$? Or, what can I do to prove that $(Z/p^n Z)^\times \simeq (Z/pZ)^\times \times (Z/p^{n-1}Z)^\times$?

Comment: There are surjections onto both factors in the direct product, and they have coprime orders, and the direct product decomposition follows. In  fact both factors are cyclic group, but you don't need that for this question.